# How to apply color filter in video in android application

Tags: android

Hello currently I am working on video editing android application, But i am not able to apply video filter in video. Anyone please suggest me the way by which i am able to apply color filter (sepia, black white) in my video in android application

Comment: i have my application source code if u need i can

Comment: not able to put my code...